# Send value of element that changed through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox

I would like to catch the value of a checkbox when the value changes and then send it through Ajax.

There are several hundred of checkboxes displayed in my HTML page, so I cannot simply send all the values when one value changes. I only want to send the value of the checkbox that just changed.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="cb_redir301" value="post_id_445">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="cb_redir301" value="post_id_573">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="cb_redir301" value="post_id_264">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="cb_redir301" value="post_id_387">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="cb_redir301" value="post_id_190">
(...)
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="cb_redir301" value="post_id_268">
```

I tried the following Javascript to catch and send the value, but it doesn't work, probably because the name of the checkbox ('cb_redir_301') is not unique.

```
$('#redir_selector').change(function(evt) {
    $.post(ajaxurl, {
        action: 'save_backend_assocs', 
        nonce:  $('#ajax_admin_redir_selector_nonce').text(),
        cb_redir301: $(this).is(':checked')
    }, function(response) {
                    });

            });

});
```

So, how can I told JS to only send the value of the checkbox that has been changed?

Comment: Where is 'redir_selector' coming from?  I think the primary reason that this isn't working is that your JQuery selector is incorrect.  You could give them all the same class name and do something like $('.someClass').change...

Comment: Please be kind and provide a jsfiddle.net or implement a code-snippet into your post.

Answer (score 1):

Faster:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
for(var i = 0 ; i < checkboxes.length ; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", updateData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution through:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){

console.log($(this).val());
```

It should work now.

Ken.